# CodeLite - Console runs but code is not working

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, console, codelite

I just installed CodeLite 6.0 in two of my PC's, however in both of these computers I get the same issue: I am able to build and run the project, but when the console starts running all I see is:

[image: screenshot of empty console window]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and if I try to add some crazy instruction that actually doesn't exist, console will still show up with no errors and the project will build with no errors, too. For example, using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    notrealcode<<"hi";
    return 0;
}
```

and `cout << "Hello World"` isn't working either.

Comment: Have you a project ? What is the output of build output ?

Comment: I dont know about codelight, but normally you have to use the correct project type in windows (gui or console) and you might only see the output when started in a cmd window (as opposed to open a new one).

Comment: @Jarod42  Yes, I do have a project and I do have built the project

Comment: @eckes I am using a console project. But nothing makes sense because when I add a line which isn't actually code recognized by C++ there seems to be no errors when built.

Comment: What is the output in build pane ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I already fixed the problem in one of my computers. I had to disable Kaspersky's security since it wasn't generating the .exe and then it worked

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you are not having a compiler installed.
See this tutorial to know how to choose and add a compiler: http://codelite.org/AddNewCompiler/AddNewCompiler

Answer (score 0):

here is how you write this code. try it !

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<"Hello world"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue due to missing libstdc++-6.dll file. There were no errors or warnings when I build and run the program. But the output console was empty. Application was not even crashing when I intentionally introduced 1/0 error.

Issue got resolved after copying libstdc++-6.dll file to the directory which has the .exe file.