# Codelite C++ program not compiling and running

Tags: c++, codelite

I installed codellite 7.0 yesterday and have been trying to work with it. But there seem to be some problem. I cannot run any code.
For now code is pretty simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("hello world\n");
return 0;
}
```

however, it returns following and output is blank with `Press any key to continue`

> Current working directory: D:\ .....
>
> Running program: le_exec.exe ./1
>
> Program exited with return code: 0

Answer (score 2):

Your program is running fine, the only problem is that after the `printf` the program returns 0 and shuts down immediately, it does run and print out "hello world", you just don't have the time to see it.

To make the program wait for user input so that you can see the output use `cin.get()` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("hello world\n");
   std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Codelite has also an option in `Project settings/General/Pause when execution ends`

Comment: Can you please give me exact location for this `Pause when execution ends`? I did not find `Project settings/General`

Comment: I also tried adding `std::cin.get()` but the result is still same. Blank terminal with `Press any key to continue`

Comment: In the settings of the project, in Common settings/general.

Comment: Also, take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977112/codelite-console-runs-but-code-is-not-working?rq=1#comment39140657_24977112